# Не удаляются пробелы из строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый вечер. Произвожу парсинг whois получаю данные потом их упорядочиваю на выходе получается вот это.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу удалить пробелы в начале, пытался всем(regexp, str_replace, trim, ltrim).
Может проблема в кодировке? И что пробел в другой кодировке? Вообщем я запутался помогите кто знает.

Comment: Выложите нормальный код, а не картинку. И покажите как именно удаляете пробелы.

Comment: trim должен вполне работать. Попробуйте вывести строки посимвольно (кодами). Если с кодировкой проблемы - будут коды "не пробела (32)". Можно их добавить в аргументы trim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте такую замену trim():

```
$text = preg_replace('%^\s+|\s+$%u', '', $text);
```

P.S. У вас там вероятнее всего страницы в UTF-8, для этого в регулярке нужно указывать модификатор `u` для php.

Comment: Отлично сработало, спасибо.